# Java Swing: Syntax Highlighting in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting, jtextpane

I am currently working on an application in Java which has an `JTextPane` editor which will contain a set of custom expressions.

I am attempting to add Syntax Highlighting to the editor which would make it easier in identifying the different expressions in the editor.

I have generated the tokens which provides the positions to be highlighted but the problem is when there is like 100+ lines of expressions in the editor, it takes a while to highlight the document when changes have been made.

I am using the following function to highlight the different parts of the expressions:

```
// StyledDocument styledDocument = editorPane.getStyledDocument();

styledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(tokenInfo.getStart(), tokenInfo.getText().length(), style, false);
```

How may I improve the performance of the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Only highlight the line that has changed.

Comment: It might help if we could see the full method that does the highlighting.  There may be more issues than just this one method call.

Comment: @camickr I thought of that but the problem will be for example the expressions which span multiple lines. If I modify an expression in that line that should affects other lines, then the other lines will not change.

Comment: Just test for highlight changes between the start position and the end position of the most recent addition or change to the text.

Comment: *but the problem is when there is like 100+ lines of expressions* - then you need to somehow find the start/end of an expression for the current line you are editing and then highlight that range of lines. For what its worth you can check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27338679/131872 which is an old attempt of mine to do Java syntax highlighting. It attempt to handle multi-line comments as described above. I doubt you will understand the code (since I don't anymore), but it does demonstrate that highlighting can be done immediately using this approach.

Comment: @camickr Thanks. I somewhat understand your methodology in in following similar I now encounter the problem of the initial load in which it would freeze the UI a bit when initially highlighting the code.

Comment: I gave you working code that demonstrates an entire 600 line file can be parsed/highlighted in under 100ms. I have no idea what your code is doing or how your parsing is working. Nobody can make any suggestions based on a single line of code.